# Refresh data in child component when routed from other pages

Tags: angular, routes

I am loading a component inside another component. How do I refresh data inside the child component when I route to the parent component from any other route.
I use this.router.navigateByUrl(`....Parent component route URL......`) which refreshes the data on parent component but the child component data does not refresh.
I have tried this.ngOnInit(); after this.router.navigateByUrl which works but it its not very efficient.
I have tried :

```
let currentUrl = this.router.url;
this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
  this.router.navigate([currentUrl]);
```

but this does not navigate to the new page. Any suggestions?

Comment: How you pass the data to the child component?

Comment: Can you put up a sample code on stackbliz ... It would be better to understand

Comment: 1. If your child component is dependent on any `@Input()` property for fetching new data then you can use `ngOnChanges()` method in your child component else, 2. You can create a subject, emit from `ngOnInit()` of your parent and subscribe to that subject in your child component to refresh the data.